# How do I add horizontal, vertical, diagonal and curved edges in this Tikz diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I draw this picture using Tikz?[image]

A MWE using Zarko's solution found here [Drawing the following diagram?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623018/drawing-the-following-diagram) :

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
    
    \begin{document}
       \begin{figure} \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 33mm and 33mm,
         N/.style = {draw, minimum size=12mm, inner sep=0pt},
                > = {Stealth[scale=0.6]},
     every edge/.append style = {draw, ->},
    every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small\linespread{0.75}\selectfont,
                                       inner sep=5pt, sloped}
                            ]
    \node [N] (A) {$S$};
    \node [N, right=of A] (B) {$A$};
    \node [N,below=of B] (C) {$I$};
    \node [N,left=of C] (D) {$R$};
    %
    \draw [<-] (A) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b\left(1-\nu\right)$};
    \draw [<-] (D) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b\nu$};
    \draw [->] (A) -- ++(0,1) node[above] {$\mu S$};
    \draw [->] (B) -- ++(0,1) node[above] {$\mu A$};
    \draw [->] ([xshift=-3.5mm] C.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\alpha I$};
    \draw [->] ([xshift=+3.5mm] C.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\mu I$};
    \draw [->] (D) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\mu R$};
    \draw[->] (B)--(D) node[midway,sloped,above]{$\gamma_A$};
    %
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
    \caption{Flow diagram for the SAIRS model.}
    \end{figure}
        \end{document}
```

Feel free to improve on this MWE.

Comment: I don't see why I got downvoted, I provided a MWE..

Comment: Just a suggestion since I'm leaving for work: try the `tkz-graph` package. It's based on TikZ which you obviously already know, and is designed to draw exactlly that sort of figure. I discovered it a few weeks ago for a graph theory lesson and am very happy with its efficiency.

Comment: I did not vote this down, but I suspect it was because on this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". If you make the Q more specific, and the example more minimal, I think you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Not really a *minimal* example, though, is it … ? I removed a bunch of unrelated packages.

Comment: Rephrase the title. What's the actual problem? Why can't you draw it yourself?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz The horizontal, vertical, diagonal and curved edges.

Comment: Then this should be in your title.

Comment: You can do that with the `tikz-cd` package.

Comment: Maybe the down vote you got because of your `beautiful` handwriting. Helpers don't want to guess your handwriting ^^ PS: I did not downvote

Comment: @Bernard Can you do it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a  solution with `tikz-cd` and `circledsteps`:

```
    \documentclass[pdf]{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd, circledsteps}

    \begin{document}

    \[ \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
     & \mu & \mu \\
    \arrow[r, "b(1-\nu)"] &\Circled{S} \arrow[r, "(\beta_AA + \beta_I I)"] \arrow[u]\arrow[d, shift right=0.75ex, "\rho", swap]& \Circled{A} \arrow[u]\arrow[ld, "\delta u", swap] \arrow[d, "\nu"]\\%
    \arrow[r, "b\nu"] &\Circled{R}\arrow[d]\arrow[u, shift right=0.75ex, "\epsilon", swap] & \Circled{I}\arrow[l, "\delta_I", swap]\arrow[d] \arrow[l, bend left, "\tau"]\\
    & \mu & \mu + \alpha
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice however I want to be consistent with my document so could you reproduce this exact diagram using my MWE?

Answer (score 0):

Do you think about this plain TikZ code? Please update a more clearly hand-drawing ^^ PS: I will finish the diagram later.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick]
\def\a{4}
\path[nodes={circle,draw,minimum size=12mm}]
(0,0)   node[fill=yellow] (R) {$R$}
(\a,0)  node[fill=red]    (I) {$I$}
(\a,\a) node[fill=cyan]   (A) {$A$}
(0,\a)  node[fill=green]  (S) {$S$}
;
\draw[->] (A)--(R) node[midway,sloped,above]{$\delta_a$};
\draw[->] (I)--(R) node[midway,above]{$\delta_I$};
\draw[->] (I.-135) to[bend left] node[midway,below]{$\tau$} (R.-45);
\draw[->] (S)--+(0,1.5) node[above]{$\mu$};
\draw[<-] (S)--+(-2,0) node[above]{$b(1-\mu)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Flow diagram for the SAIRS model.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The writing is not important aha! though I do like your humour, it made me smile :) I just need the arrows in place!