# How to flip this figure?

Tags: typography

Consider:

```
 \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1SAIRSI.pdf}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1SAIRSII.pdf}
        \end{subfigure}\\[1ex]
        \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1SAIRSIII.pdf}
        \end{subfigure}
        \setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
        \caption{Plot of system (4.1)-(4.4) with $\beta_A=0.2$, $\beta_I=0.1$, $b=0.55$, $\mu=0.01$, $\nu=0.8$, $\rho=0.1$, $\xi =0.001$, $\gamma_A =0.15$, $\gamma_I=0.1$, $\sigma=0.2$, $\eta=0.7$ and $\alpha=0.01$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.9265$.}
        \setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

How do I flip the above MWE so its of the form:

x
x|x

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable. It seems that some needed  packages are not loaded. Also use images which are available to all (for example `example-image`). A better sketch, what you like to get would be very helpful :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure guessing .. are you after the following?

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

I got above image after added missed `subcaption` package, rearranged your preamble (deleted are packages loaded twice) and use `example˙ images provided by LaTeX. I must confess, that I don't understand, what you mean with "flip", so probably position of images are not as you wish.

At least MWE can help you to correct your question that it will become more clear.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-A}%{1SAIRSI.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}

\medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-B}%{1SAIRSII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-C}%{1SAIRSIII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
%    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\caption{Plot of system (4.1)-(4.4) with $\beta_A=0.2$, $\beta_I=0.1$, $b=0.55$, $\mu=0.01$, $\nu=0.8$, $\rho=0.1$, $\xi =0.001$, $\gamma_A =0.15$, $\gamma_I=0.1$, $\sigma=0.2$, $\eta=0.7$ and $\alpha=0.01$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.9265$.}
%    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
It seems that image in the first row should be centered. For this you only need insert `\centering` after `\begin{figure}:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
```

With this changes result of compilation is:

[image]

Comment: This is almost what I'd like, I just want the position A image to be aligned centrally with B and C!

Comment: @Math, you should tell this in question ;-). You only need to add `\centering` command after `\begin{figure}`. See edited answer.

Comment: I should have but I missed it... Thank you for answering a lot of my questions, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Please could you have a look at this question; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644770/how-do-i-add-horizontal-vertical-diagonal-and-curved-edges-in-this-tikz-diagra you answered a similar one before(attached in question) but I cant manage to get a similar picture this time around..

Comment: I already did and wrote comment there. See it :-)

Comment: Not on the one I linked above!