# How to draw this TikZ figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
    \begin{document}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\begin{figure} \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 33mm and 33mm,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum size=12mm, inner sep=0pt},
            > = {Stealth[scale=0.6]},
 every edge/.append style = {draw, ->},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small\linespread{0.75}\selectfont,
                                   inner sep=5pt, sloped}
                        ]
\node [N] (A) {$S$};
\node [N, right=of A] (B) {$A$};
\node [N,below=of B] (C) {$I$};
\node [N,left=of C] (D) {$R$};
%
\draw [<-] (A) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b\left(1-\nu\right)$};
\draw [<-] (D) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b\nu$};
\draw [->] (A) -- ++(0,1) node[above] {$\mu S$};
\draw [->] (B) -- ++(0,1) node[above] {$\mu A$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=-3.5mm] C.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\alpha I$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=+3.5mm] C.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\mu I$};
\draw [->] (D) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\mu R$};
\draw[->] (B)--(D) node[midway,sloped,above]{$\gamma_A$};
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\caption{Flow diagram for the SAIRS model.}
\end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

What I'd like is:

[image]

I'd like it to be similar to this format./layout using tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}    

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 11mm and 33mm,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum size=12mm, inner sep=0pt},
            > = {Stealth[scale=0.6]},
every edge/.append style = {draw, ->},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small\linespread{0.75}\selectfont,
                                       inner sep=5pt, sloped}
                            ]
\node [N] (A) {$S$};
\node [N,above right=of A] (B) {$I_1$};
\node [N,below right=of A] (C) {$I_2$};
\node [N,above right=of C] (D) {$J$};
\node [N,right=of D] (E)  {$A$};
%
\draw [<-] (A) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$\mu$};
\draw [->] (A) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu S$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=3.75mm] B.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\nu I_1$};
\draw [->] (C) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu I_2$};
\draw [->] (D) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu J$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=-3.5mm] E.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\alpha A$};
    \draw [->] ([xshift=+3.5mm] E.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\nu A$};
    %
\draw   ([yshift=+1mm] A.east)
                edge [ultra thick, draw=gray,"\slash\slash\slash" anchor=center,
                      "$\begin{gathered}
                            p\beta_1 S I_2\\
                            q\beta_2 S J\\
                            r\beta_3 S A
                        \end{gathered}$" ] (B.west)
            ([yshift=-1mm] A.east)
                edge [ultra thick, draw=gray,"\slash\slash\slash" anchor=center,
                      "$\begin{gathered}
                            (1-p)\beta_2 S I_2\\
                            (1-q)\beta_2 S J\\
                            (1-r)\beta_3 S A
                        \end{gathered}$" '] (C.west)
           (B) edge [rotate=90,"$\epsilon I_1$"] (C)
            (D.west) edge ["$\xi_1 J$"  ] ( B.east)
            ( C.east) edge ["$p_1 I_2$"  ] (D.west)
            ([yshift=-2mm] D.west) edge ["$\xi_2 J$" '] ([yshift=-2mm] C.east)
        (D) edge ["$p_2 J$"] (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

Why doesn't this code work:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
        \begin{document}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
    \begin{figure} \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 33mm and 33mm,
         N/.style = {draw, minimum size=12mm, inner sep=0pt},
                > = {Stealth[scale=0.6]},
     every edge/.append style = {draw, ->},
    every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small\linespread{0.75}\selectfont,
                                       inner sep=5pt, sloped}
                            ]
    \node [N] (A) {$S$};
    \node [N, right=of A] (B) {$A$};
    \node [N,below=of B] (C) {$I$};
    \node [N,left=of C] (D) {$R$};
    %
    \draw [<-] (A) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b\left(1-\nu\right)$};
    \draw [<-] (D) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b\nu$};
    \draw [->] (A) -- ++(0,1) node[above] {$\mu S$};
    \draw [->] (B) -- ++(0,1) node[above] {$\mu A$};
    \draw [->] ([xshift=-3.5mm] C.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\alpha I$};
    \draw [->] ([xshift=+3.5mm] C.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\mu I$};
    \draw [->] (D) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\mu R$};
    %
    \draw
     (A) edge [rotate=90,"$\rho S$"] (D)
     (A) edge ["$(\beta_A A+\beta_I I)S$"]
     (B) edge["$\sigma A$"](C)
     ([yshift=-2mm] B.west) edge ["$\gamma_A A$" '] ([yshift=-2mm] D.east)
     (C) edge["$\gamma_I$"](D)
     (C) edge[bend left,"$\eta$"](D)
     (D) edge ["$\xi R$"] (A)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
    \caption{Flow diagram for the SAIRS model.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's recommended to include the image output of your current code. Easier for us to look at.

Comment: [Creating double arrow / parallel arrows with tikz - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56530/creating-double-arrow-parallel-arrows-with-tikz) should work for you? Anything else you need help with?

Comment: Take a look at the [Automata Drawing Library](https://tikz.dev/library-automata) wich is easy to use.

Comment: I took liberty and make your second MWE compilable. BTW, you got nice answer. I would use it. About consistency: for example that you start to saw wood by hand saw, but then you get opportunity to get motorized chain saw ... would you still further saw by hand due to consistency?

Comment: @Zarko I understand your analogy, however I like the aesthetics of the solution you provided in the other flow diagram(small arrow heads, square nodes, spaced out so diagram doesn't look squashed) :)

Comment: Your second MWE has the following errors: (i) missed is `begin{document}`, (ii) instead of ` (C) bend edge["$\eta$"](D)` should be `(C) edge[bend left, "$\eta$"] (D)`.  BTW, result of corrected MWE is not even close to your sketch (shape of nodes, direction of arrow from A)

Comment: Als with `tikz-cd` you can draw square nodes, if this is problem. Just don't use `circle` shape for nodes :-)

Comment: @Zarko Fixed some errors you pointed out. It still does not compile, the error:  `! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \begingroup 
l.2964      (A) edge [rotate=90,"$\rho S$"] (D)
                                               
? `

Comment: Apparently you have more errors. I will detailed check it later.

Comment: Any news? Now you have two answers ... one also contain corrected code from your question ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A wee bit modified nice @Luis Turcio answer (+1):

- a bit shorter code due to use a bit different (shorter) syntax
- with square shape for main nodes (as OP wish to have)
- bigger distances between nodes

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,            % <--- new
           diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
           }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[%nodes in empty cells,
                   cells={nodes={draw,anchor=center}},
                   sep=huge]
|[draw=none]|
   & |[draw=none]|\mu 
        & |[draw=none]|\mu       \\
|[draw=none]|\rar["b(1-\nu)"] 
    & S \uar
        \rar["(B_A H B_I I)"]
        \dar[shift right,"\rho"'] 
        & A \uar
            \dar["\delta"]
            \dlar["\delta_a" ']  \\
|[draw=none]|\rar["b\nu"] 
    & R \dar
        \uar[shift right,"\varepsilon" '] 
        & I \dar
            \lar[shift right,"\delta_I" ']
            \lar[shift left,bend left,"\tau"] \\
|[draw=none]|
    & |[draw=none]|\mu 
        & |[draw=none]|\mu+\alpha
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding your MWE in edited part of question:

- package had to be loaded before `\begin{document}`
- second command for drawing arrows is not terminated by `\\`
- second line in drawing arrows has not defined target coordinate (consequently edges have wrong positions)

Correcting this, your code can be compiled without any problem. But result is probably not what you are after:

[image]

It seems that you make mistake at selecting arrows coordinates.

**Addendum:**
I assume, that your code should be something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure} \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 33mm and 33mm,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum size=12mm, inner sep=0pt},
            > = Stealth,
       every edge/.append style = {draw, ->},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small\linespread{0.75}\selectfont,
                                   inner sep=5pt}
                            ]
\node [N]               (A) {$S$};
\node [N,right=of A]    (B) {$A$};
\node [N,below=of B]    (C) {$I$};
\node [N, left=of C]    (D) {$R$};
    %
\draw [<-] (A) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b\left(1-\nu\right)$};
\draw [<-] (D) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b\nu$};
\draw [->] (A) -- ++( 0,1) node[above] {$\mu S$};
\draw [->] (B) -- ++( 0,1) node[above] {$\mu A$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=-3.5mm] C.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\alpha I$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=+3.5mm] C.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\mu I$};
\draw [->] (D) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\mu R$};
    %
\draw
     (A.260) edge ["$\rho S$" '] (D.100)
     (A) edge ["$(\beta_A A+\beta_I I)S$"]  (B)
     (B) edge ["$\delta$" '] (C)
     (B) edge["$\sigma A$"] (D)
     (C) edge["$\gamma_I$"](D)
     (C) edge[bend left,"$\eta$"](D)
     (D.80) edge ["$\xi R$" '] (A.280)
     ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt} % is really needed?
    \caption{Flow diagram for the SAIRS model.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you :) The code isnt compiling on  my computer with the error `! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \begingroup 
l.2965      (A.260) edge ["$\rho S$" '] (D.100)
                                               
? `

Comment: do you know any fixes?

Comment: @Math, my MWE compile without any error, warnings or bad boxes. So I haven't any clue, what is cause of your error. It is not in MWE as it is. You change something or you have an ancient LaTeX installation. Try to upgrade it.

Comment: ok I tried on a fresh file and it works.. so do you know why it doesn't it work on my actual document?

Comment: @Math, how should i know? I didn't see it.  I can't test it. I don't know how you use proposed solution. Apparently you have some error in it which you eliminate by fresh installation. Sorry, I haven't crystal ball to see what is going on in your place ;-)

Comment: I just copy and paste the solution!

Comment: @Math, Analysis of your errors I made in comments below your question as well as in my answer below the first image. In second part of answer (in edit) is corrected your code given in edited part of your question. In case of copy/past is fine to delete any `.aux` and `.log` files or make fresh document.

Answer (score 9):

This kind of diagrams are easy with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black,circle,anchor=center}},column sep=large]
& |[draw=none]|\mu & |[draw=none]|\mu\\
|[draw=none]|{}\ar{r}{b(1-\nu)} & S\ar{u}\ar{r}{(B_A H B_I I)}\ar[shift right]{d}[swap]{\rho} & A\ar{u}\ar{d}{\delta}\ar{dl}[swap]{\delta_a}\\
|[draw=none]|{}\ar{r}{b\nu} & R\ar{d}\ar[shift right]{u}[swap]{\varepsilon} & I\ar[shorten > = -1.9ex]{d}\ar[shift right]{l}[swap]{\delta_I}\ar[shift left,bend left=20]{l}{\tau}\\
& |[draw=none]|\mu & |[draw=none]|\mu+\alpha
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although this is not like the format I want it is a nice answer so +1 :)

Comment: Whats wrong with the format?

Comment: What I meant is, I provided a similar but different flow diagram for a different section in my document so I'd like to format of the diagrams to be consistent.