# Code for Tikz picture giving error?

Tags: typography

From Zarko's solution here: [How to draw this TikZ figure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647934/how-to-draw-this-tikz-figure/647971#647971), why isnt this code working?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure} \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 33mm and 33mm,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum size=12mm, inner sep=0pt},
            > = Stealth,
       every edge/.append style = {draw, ->},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small\linespread{0.75}\selectfont,
                                   inner sep=5pt}
                            ]
\node [N]               (A) {$S$};
\node [N,right=of A]    (B) {$A$};
\node [N,below=of B]    (C) {$I$};
\node [N, left=of C]    (D) {$R$};
    %
\draw [<-] (A) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b\left(1-\nu\right)$};
\draw [<-] (D) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$b\nu$};
\draw [->] (A) -- ++( 0,1) node[above] {$\mu S$};
\draw [->] (B) -- ++( 0,1) node[above] {$\mu A$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=-3.5mm] C.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\alpha I$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=+3.5mm] C.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\mu I$};
\draw [->] (D) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\mu R$};
    %
\draw
     (A.260) edge ["$\rho S$" '] (D.100)
     (A) edge ["$(\beta_A A+\beta_I I)S$"]  (B)
     (B) edge ["$\delta$" '] (C)
     (B) edge["$\sigma A$"] (D)
     (C) edge["$\gamma_I$"](D)
     (C) edge[bend left,"$\eta$"](D)
     (D.80) edge ["$\xi R$" '] (A.280)
     ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt} % is really needed?
    \caption{Flow diagram for the SAIRS model.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \begingroup 
l.2959      (A.260) edge ["$\rho S$" '] (D.100)
                                               
?
```

EDIT:

A similar code earlier in my document works:

```
\begin{figure} \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 11mm and 33mm,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum size=12mm, inner sep=0pt},
            > = {Stealth[scale=0.6]},
 every edge/.append style = {draw, ->},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small\linespread{0.75}\selectfont,
                                   inner sep=5pt, sloped}
                        ]
\node [N] (A) {$S$};
\node [N,above right=of A] (B) {$I_1$};
\node [N,below right=of A] (C) {$I_2$};
\node [N,above right=of C] (D) {$J$};
\node [N,right=of D] (E)  {$A$};
%
\draw [<-] (A) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$\mu$};
\draw [->] (A) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu S$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=3.75mm] B.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\nu I_1$};
\draw [->] (C) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu I_2$};
\draw [->] (D) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu J$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=-3.5mm] E.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\alpha A$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=+3.5mm] E.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\nu A$};
%
\draw   ([yshift=+1mm] A.east)
            edge [ultra thick, draw=gray,"\slash\slash\slash" anchor=center,
                  "$\begin{gathered}
                        p\beta_1 S I_2\\
                        q\beta_2 S J\\
                        r\beta_3 S A
                    \end{gathered}$" ] (B.west)
        ([yshift=-1mm] A.east)
            edge [ultra thick, draw=gray,"\slash\slash\slash" anchor=center,
                  "$\begin{gathered}
                        (1-p)\beta_2 S I_2\\
                        (1-q)\beta_2 S J\\
                        (1-r)\beta_3 S A
                    \end{gathered}$" '] (C.west)
       (B) edge [rotate=90,"$\epsilon I_1$"] (C)
        (D.west) edge ["$\xi_1 J$"  ] ( B.east)
        ( C.east) edge ["$p_1 I_2$"  ] (D.west)
        ([yshift=-2mm] D.west) edge ["$\xi_2 J$" '] ([yshift=-2mm] C.east)
    (D) edge ["$p_2 J$"] (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\caption{Flow diagram for the HIV/AIDS model.}
\end{figure}
```

I don't know why this one in particular is causing issues..

EDIT 2:

My preamble(well it was a template given, I know its very old!) is causing the error as it was working before adding my preamble. Any fixes to the preamble are welcome are welcome.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rsfso}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,maxbibnames=99,sortcites=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\allowdisplaybreaks



\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\providecommand{\U}[1]{\protect\rule{.1in}{.1in}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{Theorem}[theorem]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{Fact}[theorem]{Fact}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{fact}[theorem]{Fact}
\newtheorem{lma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Property}[theorem]{Property}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{Comment}[theorem]{Comment}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}


\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\cvgpr}{\xrightarrow{\text{\upshape\tiny P}}}
\newcommand{\cvgdist}{\xrightarrow{\mathrm{d}}}
\newcommand{\G}{{\mathcal{G}}}
\newcommand{\ls}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}}
\newcommand{\rE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\A}{{\mathcal{A}}}
\newcommand{\rP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\p}{{\mathbb{P}}}
\newcommand{\Z}{{\mathbb{Z}}}
\newcommand{\re}{\mathrm{e}}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\qand}{\quad\mbox{and}\quad}
\newcommand{\quso}{\quad\mbox{so}\quad}
\newcommand{\Ups}{{\Upsilon}}
\newcommand{\iu}{{i\mkern1mu}}
\newcommand{\II}{{\mathcal{I}}}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\I}{{\mathbf 1}}
\newcommand{\R}{{\mathbb R}}
\newcommand{\N}{{\mathbb N}}
\newcommand{\LL}{{\mathbb L}}
\newcommand{\E}{{\mathbb{E}}}
\newcommand{\ri}{\mathrm{i}}
\newcommand{\rd}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\XXi}{\Xi_{k,m}^{(n)}}
\newcommand{\xxi}{\bar{\xi}}
\newcommand{\eqdef}{\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}}
\newcommand{\eqdist}{\stackrel{\mathrm{D}}{=}}
\newcommand{\braket}[2]{{\langle{#1|#2}\rangle}}
\newcommand{\independent}{\perp}
\newcommand{\F}{{\mathcal{F}}}
\newcommand{\cross}{\mathbin{\tikz [x=1.4ex,y=1.4ex,line width=.075ex] \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) (0,1) -- (1,0);}}%
\newcommand\widebar[1]{\mathop{\overline{#1}}}
\def\Plus{\texttt{+}}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{\textbf{#2#1#3}}
\crefname{figure}{\textbf{Fig.}}{\textbf{Figures}}
```

Comment: Does the example raise the error? I don't think so.

Comment: @egreg the edit I provided, it doesn't raise an error.

Comment: @egreg Trying the main code on a fresh file, it works without any issues, do you know why it isn't working on my main document? Shall I add in my preamble?

Comment: Try and add what makes the error. Copy the whole document in a fresh document and just keep the preamble and the diagram. If no error appears, then you know it's something between `\begin{document}` and the picture (which is unlikely). Otherwise, try and comment out parts of the preamble until you arrive to a minimal set that raises the error.

Comment: The error occurs with just the preamble and diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really prune that preamble and use correct ordering. Anyway, the error is due to a missing Ti*k*Z library, namely `babel` (the error is triggered by `csquotes`).

```
\usetikzlibrary{babel,arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
```

Comment: Genius, appreciate this dearly :)

Comment: My example works also without `babel` library, but its use doesn't harm ...

Answer (score 0):

Copying your code and running it in MikTex via LuaLatex results in this image; same with pdflatex:

[image]

**More investigations**:
Running TeXworks

- pdfTex: fails
- pdfLatex: "undefined control sequence \documentclass ..."
- pdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTex: OK (i.e. draws the image)
- LuaTex: doesn't know Tikz at all etc.
- LuaLatex: OK
- LuaLatex+MakeIndex+BibTex: seems to be OK
- XeTex: "undefined control sequence \documentclass ..."
- XeLatex: misses a package

ok, just to give you an impression.

Comment: I understand the code should work, but why isn't it working for me!?

Comment: No problem for me neither using `LaTeX`.

Comment: @Math, so it must be a problem "outside" of code, like configuration, options or similar. Which Latex compiler do you use? GUI-based, or run from a terminal / console?

Comment: I'm using Texworks

Comment: @Math, added more to my answer

Comment: I'm using pdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTex and same error..

Comment: Delete or comment out parts on a file duplicate, until it runs. Add code in at least one way, until it fails. Draw conclusions to localize the true problem.

Comment: Ok, it worked in a fresh file. Adding my preamble in test document caused it to give an error. So the issue is with the preamble.. I've attached it as an edit in the question.